# Cloning a DOM node list and accessing members are undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a DOM node list `arr1` that is being cloned `arr2` and I wonder whether it has been cloned properly as both behave differently. I cannot seem to access the members of arr2 as they return undefined.

Why does this happen, and how can it be fixed?

Note that I tried cloning the same array via `arr.slice` but this errors with `Uncaught TypeError: arr.slice is not a function`

Thanks for any help here - the code is below:

```js
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('li');
console.log(arr[1]); // works

var arr2 = [].concat(arr);
console.log(arr2[1]); // undefined, & logs twice
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by Jim Thorpe you currently have a nodeList. Below is a modified snippet of your code transforming that nodeList to an array. from there array 2 is modified by extracting out the innerText of the LI giving you an array of values as an example. but at this point you could do normal array functions with the data as you choose.

```js
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('li'),
  arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList); //now its an array
console.log(arr[1]); // works

const arr2 = arr.map(function (li) { return li.innerText; });
console.log(arr2[1]); // undefined, & logs twice
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the `.slice is not a function` error, because `.querySelectorAll` does not return an `Array` – it returns a `NodeList`. A `NodeList` is an `array-like` object that doesn't share the interface an `Array` has.

You can convert the `NodeList` to a real `Array` like so:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'))
```

Or you might use spreading:

```
var arr2 = [...arr];
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a static (not live) NodeList (not array), but `concat()` allows another array as parameter value.

Try with [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
var arr2 = [].concat(...arr);
```

```js
var arr = document.querySelectorAll('li');
console.log(arr[1]); // works

var arr2 = [].concat(...arr);
console.log(arr2[1]);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While it is a correct solution, it does not answer OP's question `Why does this happen?` Can you clarify it a bit for OP?

Comment: @Mirakurun, you right, updated the answer, thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('li'));
var arr2 = [...arr];
```